# Use a Variables Value in a Condition

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements

I have a condition stored in a variable `$condition = "1==1"` and I want to use the value of the variable in a conditional statement.

```
if($condition) { //$condition should be parsed as 1==1
    return true;
}
```

Is this possible? I've tried using `var_export` but apparently that doesn't work.

```
if(var_export($condition)) {
    return true;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why? Because "$condition should be parsed as 1==1" sounds suspicious :X Where does it come from? Why does it look, how it look? And so on

Comment: Im trying to run it in a function, so the condition is passed in a variable. `conditional_func($condition, $result)`

Comment: And why don't you just pass `true` or `false` (meaning `conditional_func(1 == 1, $result)`) to the function?

Comment: Because I might have something passed in to the function like `conditional_func($var . " == 'test'", $result)`

Comment: Yes, something in this direction was my question: Why do you pass `$var . " == 'test'"`, when you could pass `$var == 'test'` instead?

Comment: Ok that works perfectly! would you be able to write it up in answer form so I can accept it? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments above we found out, that the condition itself is not the problem, but how it is passed to the function

```
conditional_func($var . " == 'test'", $result);
```

We realized, that it is not required to pass the first parameter as a string, but can use a boolean directly, thus we don't need to evaluate the string at all.

```
conditional_func($var == 'test', $result);
```

As a sidenote: @BryanMoyles answer is right regarding the question, but remember, that `eval()` is evil (you can't think of any pitfall, that may occur) and on the other hand there are only some very less quite esoteric usecases, where you can't use another approach.